# Making this SQLite query more efficient

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I develop an Android app which allows a user to view a TV Guide in various ways. One of the views is a Now/Next view which is basically a list with separators (showing channel names) with each separator followed by the current / next TV show details.

The problem I'm having is with testing my own line-up of 67 channels it takes anything from 20-30 seconds to generate the view (horribly slow for mobile apps) and I know some of my users have ~200+ channels.

The SQL query I use to get the Now/Next details for 1 channel is as follows...

```
SELECT
    b.oid AS _id,
    b.channel_oid,
    b.title,
    b.start_time,
    b.end_time
FROM epg_event b,
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
            a.channel_oid,
            a.end_time
        FROM epg_event a
        WHERE a.start_time  > datetime('now')
          AND a.channel_oid = 10029
        GROUP BY a.channel_oid
        UNION
        SELECT
            MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
            a.channel_oid,
            a.end_time
        FROM epg_event a
        WHERE a.start_time <= datetime('now')
          AND a.end_time    > datetime('now')
          AND a.channel_oid = 10029
        GROUP BY a.channel_oid
    ) c
WHERE c.start_time  = b.start_time
  AND c.channel_oid = b.channel_oid
ORDER BY b.start_time
```

That seems pretty complex for a query where I just want to pull 2 records where the start time of the first is before (or equal to) the current time and end time is after current time (Now) and the second record has a start time which matches the end time of the first (Next).

I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to query for this sort of scenario.

The epg_event table is created with the following (in order to illustrate the schema)...

```
CREATE TABLE [EPG_EVENT] (
    [oid] integer PRIMARY KEY,
    [title] varchar(50),
    [subtitle] varchar(50),
    [description] varchar(50),
    [start_time] datetime,
    [end_time] datetime,
    [channel_oid] int,
    [unique_id] varchar(50),
    [rating] varchar(50),
    [original_air_date] datetime,
    [season] int,
    [episode] int,
    [dvb_service_event_id] int,
    [dvb_table_version] int,
    [genres] varchar(50)
)
```

The query shown will return...

```
_id, channel_oid, title, start_time, end_time
10467376, 10029, Ripper Street, 2013-01-20 21:00:00, 2013-01-20 22:00:00
10467377, 10029, BBC News; Regional News and Weather, 2013-01-20 22:00:00, 2013-01-20 22:25:00
```

Comment: Must this work in Android versions before Jelly Bean? (Your query doesn't.)

Comment: @CL. : I've edited the question to show the `CREATE TABLE` used for the table. As for it working on versions before Jelly Bean, I can promise you it does - my HTC Desire running Froyo runs the query fine (albeit slowly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this part of your query is supposed to get any show that either still being aired or has not started yet:

```
    SELECT
        MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
        a.channel_oid,
        a.end_time
    FROM epg_event a
    WHERE a.start_time  > datetime('now')
      AND a.channel_oid = 10029
    GROUP BY a.channel_oid
    UNION
    SELECT
        MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
        a.channel_oid,
        a.end_time
    FROM epg_event a
    WHERE a.start_time <= datetime('now')
      AND a.end_time    > datetime('now')
      AND a.channel_oid = 10029
    GROUP BY a.channel_oid
```

But, these 2 conditions are equivalent to condition that show has not ended yet, or to:

```
    SELECT
        MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
        a.channel_oid,
        a.end_time
    FROM epg_event a
    WHERE a.end_time    > datetime('now')
      AND a.channel_oid = 10029
    GROUP BY a.channel_oid
```

Now, here you filter by known channel_oid and yet `GROUP BY` it - why? It should be simplified as

```
    SELECT
        MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
        a.channel_oid,
        a.end_time
    FROM epg_event a
    WHERE a.end_time > datetime('now')
      AND a.channel_oid = 10029
```

As far as I can tell, you are probably better off replacing `datetime('now')` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. This yields your final SQL as:

```
SELECT
    b.oid AS _id,
    b.channel_oid,
    b.title,
    b.start_time,
    b.end_time
FROM epg_event b,
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(a.start_time) AS start_time,
            a.channel_oid,
            a.end_time
        FROM epg_event a
        WHERE a.end_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          AND a.channel_oid = 10029
    ) c
WHERE c.start_time  = b.start_time
  AND c.channel_oid = b.channel_oid
ORDER BY b.start_time
```

To make it work fast, make sure to create proper indexes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401642/android-sqlite-performance-in-complex-queries/13549991#13549991) can give you some ideas how to optimize it, but on first look, you should have at least following compound indexes on `epg_event` table: `(channel_oid, start_time)` and `(channel_oid, end_time)`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got a bit of help with my original query as SQL isn't my strong point - I've no idea why the guys who helped me used GROUP BY. I've condensed my query down to the one you suggest although it only returns 1 record (the Now Showing one) so I added the UNION back in and it works. The real fix however was the compound indexes - without them your condensed query wasn't noticeably quicker but when I added them it really made a difference (1-2 seconds instead of 20-30 seconds). Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you! Compound indexes can really make your day :-)